# Guzzle MockPlugin doesn't respond with content body

Tags: php, xml, mocking, guzzle

Using the [Guzzle MockPlugin](http://guzzlephp.org/plugins/mock-plugin.html) in a PHPUnit test. I found that the response content body is null whatever I do.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug?

**Test setup**

```
$client = new Client();
$plugin = new MockPlugin();
$plugin->addResponse(new Response(200, null, "This is never sent..."));
$client->addSubscriber($plugin);

$this->httpClientFactoryMock
     ->expects($this->any())
     ->method('getClient')
     ->will($this->returnValue($client));
```

**Method under test**

```
$client = $this->httpClientFactory->getClient();
$request = $client->post($this->url, null, $content->asXML());
$response = $request->send();
```

`$response->body` doesn't have `"This is never sent..."` anywhere :(
I can however put stuff in the header, so I'm sure the plugin is working, at least to some extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I wasn't send or reading correctly.

According to [this](http://guzzlephp.org/tour/http.html) I need to read the content as `$response->getBody(true)` to read it as a string.

Some of you might have noticed the `$content->asXML()` in the post function. So I actually need to do `$response->xml()`, and remember to put the `->asXML()` on the sent content. Now it works!